# How does the recursive WITH query work in oracle? When does it go into a cycle?

Tags: oracle, recursion, cycle, recursive-query

I have a scenario where I have to display a row 'n' number of times depending on the value in its quantity column.

```
Item       Qty
abc        2 
cde        1

Item       Qty
abc        1
abc        1
cde        1
```

I am looking to convert the first table to the second.

I came across the site that I should be using the recursive WITH query.

My anchor member returns the original table.

```
SELECT ITEM, QTY
           FROM lines
          WHERE     
                JOB = TO_NUMBER ('1')
                AND ITEM IN
                       (SELECT PART
                          FROM PICK
                         WHERE DELIVERY = '2')
```

My recursive member is as follows.

```
SELECT CTE.ITEM, (CTE.QTY - 1) QTY
           FROM CTE
                INNER JOIN
                (SELECT ITEM, QTY
                   FROM LINES
                  WHERE JOB_ID = TO_NUMBER ('1')
                        AND ITEM IN
                               (SELECT PART
                                  FROM PICK
                                 WHERE DELIVERY = '2'
                                       )) T
                   ON CTE.ITEM = T.ITEM
          WHERE CTE.QTY > 1
```

My goal is to get all the parts and quantities first then and then for all parts with qty > 1 in the recursive step generate new rows to be added to the original result set and qty displayed in the new rows would be (original qty for that part - 1). The recursion would go on until qty becomes 1 for all the parts.

So this is what I had in the end.

```
WITH CTE (ITEM, QTY)
AS (
SELECT ITEM, QTY
           FROM lines
          WHERE     
                JOB = TO_NUMBER ('1')
                AND ITEM IN
                       (SELECT PART
                          FROM PICK
                         WHERE DELIVERY = '2')
UNION ALL
SELECT CTE.ITEM, (CTE.QTY - 1) QTY
           FROM CTE
                INNER JOIN
                (SELECT ITEM, QTY
                   FROM LINES
                  WHERE JOB_ID = TO_NUMBER ('1')
                        AND ITEM IN
                               (SELECT PART
                                  FROM PICK
                                 WHERE DELIVERY = '2'
                                       )) T
                   ON CTE.ITEM = T.ITEM
          WHERE CTE.QTY > 1)
  SELECT ITEM, QTY
    FROM CTE
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

I get the following error when I try the above
"ORA-32044: cycle detected while executing recursive WITH query"

How is it getting into a cycle? What did I miss in its working?

Also, Upon reading from another website If I used a "cycle clause". I was able to stop the cycle.

The clause I used was.

```
       CYCLE  
       QUANTITY   
       SET                                    
       END TO '1'                               
       DEFAULT '0'
```

If I used this before the select statement. I'm getting the desired output but I don't feel this is the right way of going about it. What exactly is the clause doing? What is the right way of using it?

Comment: Your sample data doesnt match your query.

Comment: What do you mean? The where clause? It does not affect anything. The query could just be "select item,qty from table t1". I just did not remove that part from my original problem while posting here.

Comment: Your data sample only have 1 table and  2 columns, in your example you have multiple tables and more columns.

Comment: did you saw this example ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201278/repeating-rows-based-on-column-value-in-each-row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE lines ( Item, Qty ) AS
SELECT 'abc', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
SELECT 'cde', 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE pick ( part, delivery ) AS
SELECT 'abc', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'cde', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**: Using a hierarchical query:

```
SELECT Item,
       COLUMN_VALUE AS qty
FROM   lines l
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT 1
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= l.Qty
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) t
WHERE  item IN ( SELECT part FROM pick WHERE delivery = 2 )
```

**Query 2**: Using a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH rsqfc ( item, qty ) AS (
  SELECT item, qty
  FROM   lines l
  WHERE  item IN ( SELECT part FROM pick WHERE delivery = 2 )
UNION ALL
  SELECT item, qty - 1
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  qty > 1
)
SELECT item, 1 AS qty
FROM   rsqfc;
```

**Output**:

```
ITEM | QTY
:--- | --:
abc  |   1
abc  |   1
cde  |   1
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3488ef277208c161a8e6728e71f5e07d)*